# Function that returns object vs variable object

Tags: javascript, performance

I apologize in advance if I am not using the correct lingo.

I am trying to initialize an html element to a variable inside an object at creation. This is what I currently have for my setup.

```
function elements(elementID){
  this.element = function(){
    return document.getElementById(elementID);
  }
}
```

But I am worried this will affect performance, and I want it to work like this.

```
function elements(elementID){
  this.element = document.getElementById(elementID);
}
```

But this makes it so I have to wait to initialize elements or I get null.

Which is better for performance? Is object destroyed after use for the first setup? There is a visible hiccup in my program at the beginning and I am not sure if this is the source.

Are 4 iterations of this function (only once) while updating animation every 50 milliseconds enough to cause that hiccup?

Comment: That is very unlikely to be your bottleneck unless you have a really large DOM (10,000 nodes ore more), and this function is being called over 10,000 times. By the way, that code looks really weird. How about just `function byId(id) {return document.getElementById(id)}`

Comment: 4 for my current test. But depends on how many elements are in an array. It is only called at the start. The elements function is an object constructor I want a variable that refers to html element inside the object.

Comment: I can't really follow the design intent of this function to begin with (it seems like you're unintentionally relying on a global variable), but this seems unlikely to be causing a bottleneck. Have you tried using a browser's developer tools to find out what functions it spends the most time in?

Comment: Currently reading about how to do just that.

Comment: @Katana314 I'm really hoping the OP is using `var els = new elements('some-id')` instead of `var els = elements('some-id') `. OP, your answer is NO, 4 iterations will not make any difference regardless of which function you use

Comment: I am using new keyword

Comment: is `elements` function a very intensively used function in your script?

Comment: You mean objects of elements. Yes. The constructor is only used 4 times during my test.